How can I check if a String is an hexadecimal value in Rust
If I have a string as input, like 0xc0ffee.
How can I check if this String represent an hexadecimal value ?

Is there a reason you need to perform this as a check, as opposed to just parsing it directly and getting the resulting integer value? SOMEINTTYPE::from_str_radix(&thestring, 16) will parse and return a Result, and it's usually the better way to go.

@ShadowRanger I was writing a function that could take multiple types of values: hex (0xdeadbeef or deadbeef), integer (1234), binary (0b1101). And parse the value.
My naive strategy was to detect the type of the input, then parse the value accordingly.
Using if let statements like in your response makes things a lot cleaner and more robust.

"0xdeadbeef or deadbeef" part is weird, though, because it introduces ambiguity. Is the string "10" hex 16 or decimal 10? Someone who writes "1A" as input to your program, and sees it interpreted as 26 will be quite surprised to find that "10" gets interpreted as 10 rather than 16. My recommendation would be to report "deadbeef" (without the 0x prefix) as an error, i.e. require the prefix for hexadecimals.

Generally, the correct way to do this would be to rely on the parsing functions, rather than trying to reimplement a subset of them on your own, largely because when you want to know if it's parseable as hex, it's because you actually want the parsed value in short order anyway:
// Remove the `0x` prefix if it has one
let trimmed = if thestring.starts_with("0x") { &thestring[2..] } else { &thestring[..] };

// Ask the parser to parse in base 16 and collect the parsed value if so
if let Ok(uval) = u64::from_str_radix(trimmed, 16) {
    // It's a valid u64, and uval is the parsed value
} else {
    // It wasn't a valid u64
}

Substitute the appropriate integer type if u64 isn't the goal.

Maybe there is a smarter way to do this. But I have the following:
fn is_hex(input: String) -> bool {
  // Remove the 0x at the start if present
  let hexstring: String = match input {
    ref input if input.starts_with("0x") => input[2..].to_owned(),
    _ => input
  };

  // check that all chars are an hexdigit
  hexstring.chars().all(|c| c.is_ascii_hexdigit())
}

fn main () {
  // hex strings
  let hex_string = String::from("0xc0ffee");
  assert_eq!(is_hex(hex_string), true);

  let hex_string = String::from("deadbeef");
  assert_eq!(is_hex(hex_string), true);

  // not an hex string
  let not_an_hex_string = String::from("Hi mom!");
  assert_eq!(is_hex(not_an_hex_string), false);
}


No need to make a copy, just accept the argument as &str so the types are always &str throughout (allowing you to remove .to_owned()). You'll also need to add a length check, or the all check will treat inputs of "" and "0x" as valid when they aren't.
